# Customization of QSlider

Tags: python, pyqt5, qslider

I try to make a slider, where I could change a color of selected part of groove, but I really have no idea, how it can be done.

Comment: This should be possible using a label overlay. First draw a QSlider, then put a label on top of it and set rgba style for the label. Then use label.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents) - this will force mouse events to propagate to the slider through the label on top - as the label wasn't there.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to achieve, maybe by providing a mockup of the possible final result?